# How to minimize If else statement on below? or should i use map or switch?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

```
public String identifyCellular(Long phone1, Long phone2, Long phone3) {

    String cellular = null;
    if (String.valueOf(phone2).trim().replaceAll("\\D", " ").equals("(07'\\d'{8})|(467'\\d'{8})")) {
        cellular = String.valueOf(phone2).trim().replaceAll("\\D", " ");
    } else if (String.valueOf(phone1).trim().replaceAll("\\D", " ").equals("(07'\\d'{8})|(467'\\d'{8})")) {
        cellular = String.valueOf(phone1).trim().replaceAll("\\D", " ");
    } else {
        cellular = String.valueOf(phone3).trim().replaceAll("\\D", " ");
    }
    return cellular;
}
```

Comment: Whatever `phone1`, `phone2` and `phone3` are just assign them to a generic `phone` inside the conditionals and place `cellular = String.valueOf(phone).trim().replaceAll("\\D", " ");` out of it.

Comment: Pattern matching with `equals()`?

Comment: I suppose you want to pass your phone numbers as `String` - a `Long` never starts with a 0

Answer (score 4):

It's fine. However, you could trim all 3 variables before the `if` block, refactor the regex, and return immediately inside the `if` statement.

Also, to match with regex, use `Pattern.compile()` and `Pattern.matcher()` to get the matching group. Then use `find()` to check if there is any match.

```
public String identifyCellular(Long phone1, Long phone2, Long phone3) {

    String matchedRegex = "(07'\\d'{8})|(467'\\d'{8})";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(matchedRegex);

    String phone1Trimmed = String.valueOf(phone1).trim().replaceAll("\\D", " ");
    String phone2Trimmed = String.valueOf(phone2).trim().replaceAll("\\D", " ");
    String phone3Trimmed = String.valueOf(phone3).trim().replaceAll("\\D", " ");

    if (r.matcher(phone2Trimmed).find()) {
        return phone2Trimmed;
    } else if (r.matcher(phone1Trimmed).find()) {
        return phone1Trimmed;
    } else {
        return phone3Trimmed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon me, this is plain nonsense, IMHO: on what condition would Long.toString() ever return a non-digit??

Answer (score 0):

When reading your code, I am not sure if the above algorithm is an art for art or a real need to solve the problem. Following your course, I suggest getting rid of if statements

```
public String identifyCellular(Long... phones) {
    String matchedRegex = "(07'\\d'{8})|(467'\\d'{8})";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(matchedRegex);
    Optional<Long> first = Arrays.stream(phones)
        .filter(filterMatchingNumber(pattern))
        .findFirst();
    return String.valueOf(first.orElse(giveLastPhone(phones)));    
  }

  private Long giveLastPhone(Long[] phones) {
    return phones[phones.length - 1];
  }

  private Predicate<Long> filterMatchingNumber(Pattern r) {
    return phone -> r.matcher(getPhone1Trimmed(phone)).find();
  }

  private String getPhone1Trimmed(Long phone1) {
    return String.valueOf(phone1).trim().replaceAll("\\D", " ");
  }
```

It looks like the trim and replace of a non-digit (\D) to spaces in this case is not needed. I recommend considering to skip it

```
  final String matchedRegex = "(07'\\d'{8})|(467'\\d'{8})";
  final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(matchedRegex);

  public String identifyCellular(Long... phones) {
    Optional<Long> first = Arrays.stream(phones)
        .filter(filterMatchingNumber(pattern))
        .findFirst();
    return String.valueOf(first.orElse(giveLastPhone(phones)));
  }

  private Long giveLastPhone(Long[] phones) {
    return phones[phones.length - 1];
  }

  private Predicate<Long> filterMatchingNumber(Pattern pattern) {
    return phone -> pattern.matcher(phone.toString()).find();
}
```